# How to view ip's visited in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

is there any way to view a list with a detail of the ips that visited in a day for example or with a range of dates?

Answer (score 7):

As [this Google Analytics Google Groups states](http://groups.google.com/group/analytics-help/web/are-ip-addresses-tracked-by-google-analytics?pli=1) "IP Addresses are *not* tracked by Google Analytics" at all for some reasons mentioned in the post, like "it's not reliable", "it's not scalable" and "it's Evil".

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to get this information from your web server access logs, if you own the website of course.